# Formatting a tuple of floats

Tags: python

How can I format a tuple of float to `.3f`?

```
In [1]: pi=3.14159265359

In [2]: print "{:.3f}".format(pi)
3.142

In [3]: e=2.71828182

In [4]: z=(pi,e)

In [5]: print z
(3.14159265359, 2.71828182)
```

Comment: In your code you could also do `from math import pi, e`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You format each float value *in* the tuple:

```
print ' '.join(format(f, '.3f') for f in z)
```

I used the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) here to achieve the same formatting for individual floating point values.

Output:

```
>>> pi=3.14159265359
>>> e=2.71828182
>>> z=(pi,e)
>>> print ' '.join(format(f, '.3f') for f in z)
3.142 2.718
```

Adjust the join string as needed.

Comment: Why don't you use *z, as in the answer below?

Comment: @RolfBly: Because I am using `' '.join()` on individual values of `z` to allow for a variable `len(z)`, while the other answer assumes that `len(z)` is exactly 2, always.

Comment: I see. But in this case, z is a tuple, immutable, of fixed length, no?

Comment: @RolfBly: Yes, but I assumed it was but an example.

Answer (score 7):

You could use

```
print '{:.3f} {:.3f}'.format(*z)
```